# Proove that all finite non-standard Kripke frames are standard

Tags: logic, modal-logic, kripke-models

In Harel's book on PDL (Propositional Dynamic Logic) I've learnt that Kripke frames are pairs such as:
     K = (K; $m_k$)

Where $K$ is a set called states and $m_k$ is a meaning function assigning subset of $K$ to each atomic proposition and a binary relation on $K^2$ to each atomic program:
    $m_k$ ($p$) $\subset$  $K$, where $p$ is an atomic formula; 
    $m_k$ ($\alpha$) $\subset$ $K^2$, where $\alpha$ is an atomic program.

By definition, we have:

$$m_k(\phi->\psi) = (K - m_k(\phi)) \ \bigcup \ m_k(\psi)$$
$$m_k(0) = \emptyset$$
$$m_k([\alpha]\psi) = K - (m_k(\alpha) \ o \ (K - m_k(\phi))$$
$$m_k(\alpha;\beta) = m_k(\alpha) \ o \ m_k(\beta)$$
$$m_k(\alpha \ \bigcup \ \beta) = m_k(\alpha) \ \bigcup \ m_k(\beta)$$
$$m_k(\alpha^*) = m_k(\alpha)^* = \bigcup \ m_k(\alpha)^n, where\ n>0$$
$$m_K(\psi?) = ( (u,v) \ | \ u \in m_k(\psi) ) $$
The previous definition can be extended by induction to all formulas and programs.

As Noah Schweber said below:
"The point is that the definition of "nonstandard Kripke frame" is the same as the definition of "standard Kripke frame," except that one condition is weakened: rather than having the property that $m_N(\alpha^∗)$ is the reflexive transitive closure of $m_N(\alpha^∗)$ (which is required of standard Kripke frames), a nonstandard Kripke frame merely needs to satisfy the weaker condition."

How can I show that all finite non-standard Kripke frames are standard?

Comment: @hardmath I hope that I edited it so everyone can understand the question. Please let me know if not.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think I don't get the question. Should I expand the context even more?

Comment: I'm asking (to put it by analogy) if you meant to ask if every square is a rectangle, or if every rectangle is a square?  See how you phrased your title and final sentence of Question.   Compare this to what Noah wrote.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate. I changed the question a bit. Following our analogy with squares and rectangles I could say that I want to prove that "all rectangles with a specific property are squares" (we norrow the meaning "property" adjective a lot).

Comment: The Question here is Exercise 6.5 (pg. 202) in [Dynamic Logic](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/dynamic-logic), the same book linked to by Noah Schweber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See pages 199-200 of [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZRXNOzX15d8C&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200&dq=standard+kripke+frame&source=bl&ots=JcEtqGm08u&sig=Cm1BCZ4IeWGhIZ0W-ZNpk7G6Y2U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjY-rDewLPRAhVpjlQKHQW6DJIQ6AEIKjAD#v=onepage&q=standard%20kripke%20frame&f=false). The point is that the definition of "nonstandard Kripke frame" is the same as the definition of "standard Kripke frame," except that one condition is weakened: rather than having the property that $m_\mathfrak{N}(\alpha^*)$ is the reflexive transitive closure of $m_\mathfrak{N}(\alpha)$ (which is required of standard Kripke frames), a nonstandard Kripke frame merely needs to satisfy the weaker condition $$\mbox{$m_\mathfrak{N}(\alpha^*)$ is a transitive reflexive extension of $m_\mathfrak{N}(\alpha)$ satisfying properties 5.5(vii-viii).}$$ So every standard Kripke frame is a nonstandard Kripke frame, in the same way that every rectangle is a square. (A better name for nonstandard Kripke frames might be "possibly nonstandard Kripke frames" for this reason, but that's a mouthful.)

Comment: perhaps you mean "in the same way that every square is a rectangle"?

Comment: I'm sorry , but thank to hardmath's feedback , I realised I had to change the question a little. Does this answer still stand? (no irony intended)

Comment: Hmm a better name might be "general Kripke frame" so that "nonstandard" can be used for those that are not "standard"?